# Different results decoding stellar seed in debug and build release for Android

Tags: android, flutter, dart, ed25519, stellar

Trying builded application in Google Play which is basically a stellar wallet and found that I'm getting different results with flutter run and in builded version while decoding seed or mnemonic for wallet import. How can I solve this? Is this something ed25519 specific for Android?

Dart packages used are:
https://pub.dev/packages/stellar
https://pub.dev/packages/stellar_hd_wallet

So, results are correct in debug mode running flutter run -d  and invalid deploying builded version to the device

for getting key pair from mnemonic

```dart
import 'package:stellar_hd_wallet/stellar_hd_wallet.dart';
final wallet = await StellarHDWallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
final keyPair = wallet.getKeyPair();
print(keyPair.accountId); // gives different results
```

and for getting account id

```dart
import 'package:stellar/stellar.dart' as stellar;
var keyPair = stellar.KeyPair.fromSecretSeed(seed);
print(keyPair.accountId); // gives different results
```

no errors but accountIds in results are different